# Replacing response stream in ASP.NET Core 1.0 middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I want to write Custom Middleware in my ASP.NET Core 1.0 project which will replace original framework's Http Response Stream to my own, so I will be able to perform read / seek / write operations on it (first 2 are not possible on the original stream) in the further code i.e. in Actions or Filters.

I've started with the following code:

```
public class ReplaceStreamMiddleware
{
    protected RequestDelegate NextMiddleware;

    public ReplaceStreamMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        NextMiddleware = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {       
        using (var responseStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var fullResponse = httpContext.Response.Body;
            httpContext.Response.Body = responseStream;
            await NextMiddleware.Invoke(httpContext);
            responseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            await responseStream.CopyToAsync(fullResponse);
        }   
    }
}
```

The problem with the following code is that **sometimes** the `fullResponse` stream is **already closed** at the time of invoking `await responseStream.CopyToAsync(fullResponse);` so it throws an exception *Cannot access a closed Stream.*

This weird behaviour is easy to observe when I load the page in the browser and then refresh, **before it loads completely**.

I would like to know:

1. why this happens?
2. how to prevent it?
3. is my solution a good idea or there is another way to replace response stream?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exception doesn't come from your `CopyToAsync`. It's from one of your code's callers:

You're not restoring the original response stream in `HttpContext`. Therefore, whoever calls your middleware will get back a closed `MemoryStream`.

Here's some working code:

```
app.Use(async (httpContext, next) =>
{
    using (var memoryResponse = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var originalResponse = httpContext.Response.Body;
        try
        {
            httpContext.Response.Body = memoryResponse;

            await next.Invoke();

            memoryResponse.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            await memoryResponse.CopyToAsync(originalResponse);
        }
        finally
        {
            // This is what you're missing
            httpContext.Response.Body = originalResponse;
        }
    }
});

app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/other";
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
});
```